# Parsing xls files by a coordinates [Node.JS]

Tags: node.js, parsing, xls

I've got a question. Is it possible to parse xls files by a coordinates? I've searched some npm modules but the biggest part of them are converting to json or csv. So does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [node-xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-xlsx)

It will help you to parse ".xlsx" i.e.

`const workSheetsFromFile=xlsx.parse(__dirname+'/myFile.xlsx');`

Read the documentation for more functionality.